# Windows 10 Pro upgrade from home on laptop is no longer working?

Tags: windows, updates

I bought a new laptop, saw that it came with Windows 10 home, and upgraded it to Windows 10 pro using a legit genuine expensive key.

Out of nowhere, it says "Activate Windows" and only gives me "I changed my hardware" (I didn't)

I have no way to do anything.

I can change the product key or claim that I changed hardware and that's why the key is no longer working. Those are my only options I don't get anything else. The same issue you get when you swap motherboards is the same issue I'm getting on a laptop that I just upgraded to Windows 10 Pro by entering a pro key into the activation menu as I was told to do by Microsoft.

"To upgrade to the Pro version of Windows 10, simply enter the product key into the "change product key" section on the Activation page"

Which worked because it then became the pro version. The next day it's asking me for the keys saying that my key isn't working.

I figured there might be a simple work-around for this.

Comment: Ask the outfit that sold you the Pro upgrade for assistance. I have done upgrades to Pro with the key sourced from Microsoft

Comment: What does the activation status of Windows have to do with opening the Word document? Windows has always worked to a certain degree even in an unactivated status

Comment: Where did you purchase the Pro key?

Comment: @Ramhound - I never said anything about it opening a word document I said I have a saved word document...

Comment: @freddie-o Microsoft.com and I've already contacted support.

Comment: @SidedTech - So can you open the document that contains your key using Google Docs or similar service? How did you upgrade to Windows 10 Professional exactly? Can you [edit] your question instead replying with another comment?

Comment: I don't know why everybody keeps talking about Google docs and Microsoft word I'm not saying anything about that I'm saying I have a saved word document. Word has nothing to do with anything but I will edit the question.

Comment: @SidedTech - We assumed you knew how to manually register your machine since you had done it once before.  Can you provide a sanitized screenshot of `winver` by chance?